# Identify duplicates with two fixed values and within a range in r

Tags: r, time, duplicates, range

I have large dataframe of e-mails that looks like this:

```
structure(list(messagesubject = c("Re: Fuentes/referencias para tutorial YoPeatón", 
"Re: Fuentes/referencias para tutorial YoPeatón", "Protejamos nuestras playas", 
"Protejamos nuestras playas", "Protejamos nuestras playas", "Protejamos nuestras playas", 
"Protejamos nuestras playas", "Protejamos nuestras playas", "Protejamos nuestras playas", 
"Protejamos nuestras playas", "documento", "documento", "documento"
), senderaddress = c("6607", "7998", "4799", "9731", "4799", 
"79", "9731", "4799", "9731", "4799", "1846", "1846", "1846"
), recipient = c("94529", "163910", "289", "289", "270177", "2310", 
"1118", "1118", "2551", "2551", "753", "12291", "106610"), datetimesent = structure(c(1515632629, 
1515632629, 1515632636, 1515632636, 1515632639, 1515632640, 1515632641, 
1515632641, 1515632647, 1515632647, 1515632680, 1515632680, 1515632680
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to extract e-mails with the same "messagesubject", same "senderaddress" and within a 5 seconds timeframe ("datetimesent") from each other. I´m cleaning a dataset and most probably these are just the same e-mail but delivered with lag.

I am able to extract exact repetitions with:

```
d[(duplicated(d[c(4,2,1)]) | duplicated(d[c(4,2,1)], fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

but I have no idea of how to do it considering a timeframe in "datetimesent"

The result should have lines 3,5,8 (have the same senderaddress, same messagesubject and have a maximun of 5 seconds between them, as well as lines 4 and 7. It should look like:

```
messagesubject             senderaddress recipient datetimesent       
              
1 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          289       2018-01-11 01:03:56
2 Protejamos nuestras playas 9731          289       2018-01-11 01:03:56
3 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          270177    2018-01-11 01:03:59
4 Protejamos nuestras playas 9731          1118      2018-01-11 01:04:01
5 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          1118      2018-01-11 01:04:01
```

Comment: Can a message only be duplicated once (2x messages only)? Why don't you also group on recipient?

Comment: No, it can appear many times. I´ve seen cases of more that 200 in the data. I don´t group by recipient because it is ok to have different recipients. I can send one e-mail to many people at the same time. My guess is that the e-mail is getting stuck in the server so it is delivering one e-mail at time with small time differences, instead of sending them alltogether. That´s what I want to be able to address

Comment: Why don't the "documento" messages show up in your expected results? They should meet the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
# first ensure file is in order
df<-df %>% arrange(senderaddress, datetimesent)

# if the sender address is the same, test if subject is the same
df$diffsub<-ifelse(df$senderaddress==data.table::shift(df$senderaddress,1), ifelse(df$messagesubject!=data.table::shift(df$messagesubject,1),"Different","Same Subj"),NA) 


# if diffSub is "Same Subj" compute time difference   
df$difftime<-ifelse(df$diffsub=="Same Subj",df$datetimesent-data.table::shift(df$datetimesent,1),NA)  

# if diffsub=Same Subj, email is also the same, so
df # examine
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using grouping in tidyverse. The key is to group by subject and address, order by time, then find the time difference with the previous and next message.

We can then filter for groups with multiple rows with a message <= 5 seconds before or after it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

d %>%
    group_by(messagesubject, senderaddress) %>%
    arrange(datetimesent) %>%
    mutate(lag = (datetimesent-lag(datetimesent)),     # time from previous msg
           lead = lead(datetimesent)-datetimesent) %>% # time to next msg
    filter(lag <= seconds(5) | lead <= seconds(5), # require msg within 5sec
           n() > 1)                                # require >1 msg with sub/add

# A tibble: 8 × 6
# Groups:   messagesubject, senderaddress [3]
  messagesubject             senderaddress recipient datetimesent        lag     lead   
  <chr>                      <chr>         <chr>     <dttm>              <drtn>  <drtn> 
1 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          289       2018-01-11 01:03:56 NA secs  3 secs
2 Protejamos nuestras playas 9731          289       2018-01-11 01:03:56 NA secs  5 secs
3 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          270177    2018-01-11 01:03:59  3 secs  2 secs
4 Protejamos nuestras playas 9731          1118      2018-01-11 01:04:01  5 secs  6 secs
5 Protejamos nuestras playas 4799          1118      2018-01-11 01:04:01  2 secs  6 secs
6 documento                  1846          753       2018-01-11 01:04:40 NA secs  0 secs
7 documento                  1846          12291     2018-01-11 01:04:40  0 secs  0 secs
8 documento                  1846          106610    2018-01-11 01:04:40  0 secs NA secs
```